# Which OS platform is recommened for doing native game development using Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I have some **Android** experience for building Apps using **Java**.

Recently I shifted to native development and I always preferred **Windows**. But native some time needs building using shell script /  make files.

This can be done using **cygwin** but there are few things to deal with **cygwin** and **windows**. Some times build works or some times you have to delete libs , objs and then clean build.

Can any one recommend OS platform for Native Development using **CPP**, **Cocos2DX** ?

Comment: The only valid answer to this is "the one you're comfortable with". If you're not comfortable with one, then none of them.

Comment: Well, I really had bad time with windows,cygwin and cocos2dx, So I am seriously thinking of switching to Ubuntu, but before taking final call, I would like some guidance from someone who has more experience on native developement. And I feel this question would be useful for indie game begineers

Comment: @mah No, Windows is surely more comfortable with Ubuntu but debugging native code just doesn't work under Windows good enough. Also, there are many 3rd parties librraries which you can use with  Android NDK and which are built under Ubuntu, you will have problems porting their build systems to Windows

Comment: @pradeep many questions are useful for many people, but that doesn't make the question a good fit for stack overflow. For example, nothing that gets answered using opinion, rather than subjective technical reason, is appropriate for this site.

Comment: A good pro-Ubuntu, opinion-free, argument would be that Android OS itself can be built using Ubuntu

Comment: For Cocos2dx Windows and OSX are the best options. I don't recommend you to use Linux. Also you don't need cygwin on Windows for NDK project. you can build without cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android development involving NDK using Windows is almost no option. You will have all the problems with debugging native code and also because many existing native libraries (e.g. ffmpeg) are built under Linux. Ubuntu is fine. I have not tried MacOS though.

Comment: thanks, I will update here after trying Ubuntu

Comment: Mac is very friendly for Android development in general, and native  code in particular. But from practical / budget perspective, a Ubuntu virtual machine on Windows PC is OKey.

Comment: It was easy enough to do basic set up on Ubuntu,much better than windows for NDK and Cocos2dx